# Google Maps infowindow tip blinking

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

White bottom tip of marker infowindow appears in upper left corner of map when moving mouse quickly over both markers left-right-left.

See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/WGy4g/3/

```
var map = null;

initialize();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),zoom: 8};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);    

    addMarker(-34.397, 150.644);
    addMarker(-34.377, 150.534);
}

function addMarker(lat,lng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng), title: "marker"});
    marker.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        if (!this.infowindow) {
            this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'abc'});
        }
        this.infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.infowindow.close();
    });
}
```

Posted a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6746&thanks=6746&ts=1401343988

Comment: Strange. You actually don't need to create a new infowindow each time. Create one with a global scope `var infowindow = new google.maps.infowindow();`. Then you can just call `infowindow.setContent('...');` when you want to change the content and `infowindow.open(map, marker);` to show it. But the blinking issue is still present. I can see that the same happens on all examples in the official documentation...

Comment: @MrUpsidown, this is an example, there can be tons of good reasons for binding infowindows objects to the marker themselves. And as you notice, it does not solve the problem anyway :)

Comment: +1, very strange. Have never noticed that before, but it seems to be rather consistent. Maybe a newly "bug" or side effect of some change somewhere? The version used is 3.16.

Comment: @davidkonrad There could be good reasons. From what I see in the example, there would be no need. But that was just a hint. FYI, I have tried without specifing the API version and the same happens.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, davidkonrad, I actually use single infowindow in my project, you are both right.

Comment: And if you drag map around, that "ghost" marker moves, too.

Comment: To use something other than the "experimental" or "released" version in the free API you need to specify it as v=3.15 (that is the current "frozen" version, and the oldest available version). [Versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

Comment: But it [still happens in 3.15 as well](http://jsfiddle.net/WGy4g/27/)

Comment: Unless someone can point out something wrong with your code, I think you should [file a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) to have Google team to look at it.

Comment: [bug report in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6746)

Comment: This is strange. It's also happening on googles infowindow example page. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple, Also as @MrUpsidown said, you only need one instance of infowindow: http://jsfiddle.net/WGy4g/3/

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Google map js api version 3 infowindow glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219179/google-map-js-api-version-3-infowindow-glitch)

I can confirm that this happens in both IE and Google Chrome. It appears to be an issue with the Google Maps API, therefore you were right to list this as a bug. To try working around the problem in one of my own scripts, I have tried; using the **setPosition** method of the InfoWindow class to set specific LatLng coordinates to 0,0 before invoking the **open** method; and fiddling around with the **pixelOffset** property through the **setOptions** method, but to no avail. I also considered changing the visibility state of the InfoWindow back and forth, but there is no easy way of doing this.

Waiting for the bug to be fixed appears to be the only feasible option.